# Call a number through application in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to call a number within the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the below link for the same

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://9016098909891"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* theNumber = @"9994441234";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"tel:%@", theNumber]]];
```

Comment: @hypercrypt: Yeah that's python string formatting leaking in.  Thanks, I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the uitextview and enable phone detection. After that the phone number will look like hyperlinked. Use the following code.

```
mytextview.text = @"9943586256";
mytextview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
mytextview.editable=NO;
```

Helpful if you want to show the phone number inside a custom tableview cell.